# Call Selector with Multiple Arguments and from Different Class for Bar Button

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, selector, uibarbuttonitem

I have one `Objective - C Class` ( named `Constants` ) with some `Method` having one `Argument` say...

```
+(void)someMethod :(id)arg
{
     //Some Stuff...
}
```

I want to attach this Method to some `UIBarButtonItem` ( which is added in some `Navigation Bar` of some other `UIViewController`). I have `rightBarButton` in Navigation Bar.

```
UIBarButtonItem *rightBarButton = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithTitle:@"someTitle" style:UIBarButtonItemStyleBordered target:self action:@selector(someMethod)];
```

**Question :** What is the Optimum way to call that `-someMethod` from some `Other Class` with some `Argument` ?

**Update :**

I found that we can use `Class Object` of that `Constant Class` in `target` to call `-someMethod` from some other `View Controller`, but that method contains `Argument` and how to pass argument in this case.

Comment: what data u need in arg in method??

Comment: @SatishAzad : It can be any thing a String, Integer, Float or some Object also.

Comment: when u try to call using this:
UIBarButtonItem *rightBarButton = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithTitle:@"someTitle" style:UIBarButtonItemStyleBordered target:self action:@selector(someMethod:)];

then arg gives Object reference of UIBarButton.

Comment: @SatishAzad: Let's say I want to pass Object of `UIViewController`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to use this flow:

```
+(void)someMethod :(id)arg
{
     //Some Stuff...
     //Your DataObject is received
}    

-(void)buttonCall:(id)sender
{
     [OtherClassObjOrName someMethod:YourDataObject];
}

//add button 
UIBarButtonItem *rightBarButton = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithTitle:@"someTitle" style:UIBarButtonItemStyleBordered target:self action:@selector(buttonCall:)];
```

You can call your someMethod by using self if inside same class or classObject if call is needed in another class.

Comment: Re-check my Question. I asked for Optimum way. We all know that , we can do it like this. I have method in some other Class and I directly want to connect that method to my Bar Button (of course with passing the Argument).

Comment: If u connect directly that method to ur ButtonAction then how can u decide which data u need to pass either a string or a ViewController or a Array or Dict...???

Comment: As I told you, I want to pass ViewController Object.

Comment: What makes you think there is a more optimum solution than this?

Comment: @isaac: Here we are adding central method `-buttonCall` (only work of it to call another method). Don't you think, it's too lengthy ?

Comment: Yes, you're adding an additional method, but that overhead is negligible. The trouble is that - as you can see - the method that attaches a selector to a button doesn't support passing parameters. Although the sender is always passed implicitly, that's not what you want in this case. While there are a few other approaches, frankly none of them are as simple as clean, simple, or fitting with Cocoa conventions as this one. If you really want another approach consider exploring an [NSInvocation](http://www.cocoawithlove.com/2008/03/construct-nsinvocation-for-any-message.html).

Answer (score 0):

You can use associated objects to attach a piece of information on the bar button item.

The simplest way to do this is to find one of many "block-based" APIs for bar button item that are on the Internet, and use a block instead of selector-target.